# What sort of unit does NetTopologySuite return distances in, and how can I convert it to miles/km?

Tags: c#, geometry, nettopologysuite

Whenever I use FreeMapTools to calculate the distance between myself and my friends postcode, it gives me the following:

- 300.788 Miles
- 484.072 KM

[image: Screenshot from FreeMapTools showing 300.788 Miles]
[image: Screenshot from FreeMapTools showing 484.072 KM]

When I use NetTopologySuite, I get the value of **5.2174236612815** returned.

- **5.2174236612815** times by 60 is *313.04541967689*
- **5.2174236612815** times by 100 is *521.74236612815*

These values aren't too far away from the distances shown on FreeMapTools, but they are still way off.

My code is below:

```
using System;
using GeoAPI.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite;

namespace TestingDistances
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);

            // BT2 8HB
            var myPostcode = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(-5.926223, 54.592395));

            // DT11 0DB
            var myMatesPostcode = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(-2.314507, 50.827157));

            var distance = myPostcode.Distance(myMatesPostcode);
            Console.WriteLine(distance); // returns 5.2174236612815

            Console.WriteLine(distance * 60); //similar to miles (313.04541967689)
            Console.WriteLine(distance * 100); //similar to km (521.74236612815)

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about converting the value returned from NetTopologySuite accurately into miles/distances? Is this some form of GPS distancing unit I'm not aware off?

Thanks

Comment: This might be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#srid-ignored-during-client-operations

Comment: That feeling when you spend days pouring through documentation then find someone who's already been through this pain...   The documentation for NetTopologySuite is terrible IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As DavidG mentions correctly, NetTopologySuite assumes cartesian coordinates. Your coordinates are geographic (lat/lon). Thus the result you are getting is useless and cannot be translated into meter or miles.

You have to perform a coordinate transformation prior to calling the distance method, e.g. using ProjNet:

```
var csWgs84 = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystems.WGS84;
const string epsg27700 = "..."; // see http://epsg.io/27700
var cs27700 = ProjNet.Converters.WellKnownText.CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(epsg27700);
var ctFactory = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
var ct = ctFactory.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csWgs84, cs27700);
var mt = ct.MathTransform;

var gf = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.GeometryFactory(27700);

// BT2 8HB
var myPostcode = gf.CreatePoint(mt.Transform(new Coordinate(-5.926223, 54.592395)));
// DT11 0DB
var myMatesPostcode = gf.CreatePoint(mt.Transform(new Coordinate(-2.314507, 50.827157)));

double distance = myPostcode.Distance(myMatesPostcode);
```

Comment: what is the unit of the above distance? And how can I convert it into meters?

Comment: It is in the unit of the target coordinate system (EPSG:27700). Accroding to https://epsg.io/27700 it is in meters.

Comment: Why “epsg27700”? Only condition is unit to be in meters?

Comment: Because it is a spatial reference system that suits the example.

Comment: It appears the NuGet package must be different now as `ProjNet.Converters` isn't found.  Is there any update please as the documentation isn't obvious?

Comment: The package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProjNet

Comment: Yes thanks @FObermaier I got it before posting, but can't fathom out the new way of doing what you did above with `Converters`.  There aren't any modern online examples that I can find.  Might be a new SO question required perhaps...

Comment: If you've got a few minutes please, here's an update using your code plus other reading materials I've stumbled through... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306799/how-to-measure-distance-between-two-points-in-metres-with-nettopologysuite-pro

Answer (score 4):

The number appears to just be a simple Cartesian coordinate system. For example:

```
var point1 = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(0, 0));
var point2 = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(0, 270));

var distance = point1.Distance(point2);
```

Here `distance` is 270. If we use `0, 0` and `30, 40` the distance is `50`. That's just a simple Pythagoras calculation (i.e. `30^2 + 40^2 = 50^2`)

Comment: You've lost me. Where are you getting 270 from again?

Comment: Just example numbers to demonstrate how it works

Comment: This appears to be a circular reference. If the end result `distance` is 270, that's the value we started out with, i.e. `new Coordinate(0, 270)`. Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: The calculated value is the distance from `point1` to `point2`, I'm not really sure what you are asking here?

Comment: I'm just finding it odd that we've started out with 270 and ended up with 270.

Comment: The distance between 2 points on a graph where the points are located at 0,0 and 0,270 is 270

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Don't know why I wasn't seeing that. Simple stuff. Thanks for sticking with me throughout.